# Incrementing Clocks

Tags: linux, operating-system, freebsd

When a process is set to run with an initial time slice of 10 for example, someone in the hardware should know this initial timeslice and decrement it and when the time slice turns 0, an interrupt should be fired!

In freeBSD kernel, I understand that hardclock and the softclock does this task of accounting. But my question is, is this decrementing of clock parallel to the execution of the process?

Comment: Please read some resources about [preemptive scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) and related topics.

Comment: I did read about those.. But then I am not able to get a clear picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the PIT as an example here, because it's the simplest timing mechanism (and has been around for quite a while).

Also, this answer is fairly x86-specific; and also OS-agnostic. I don't know enough about the internals of FreeBSD and Linux to answer for them specifically. Someone else might be more capable of that.

Essentially, the timeslice is "decremented" parallel to the execution of the process as the timer creates an IRQ for each "tick" (note that timers such as the HPET can do 'one-shot' mode, which fires an IRQ after a specific delay, which can be used for scheduling as well). Once the timeslice decrements to zero, the scheduler is notified and a task switch occurs. All this happens "at the same time" as your process: the IRQ jumps in, runs some code, then lets your process keep going until the timeslice runs out.

It should be noted that, generally speaking, you don't see a process running to the end of it's timeslice as task switches can occur as the direct result of a system call (for example, a read from disk that blocks, or even writing to a terminal).

Comment: Superb... This is kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This was simpler in the misty past: a clock chip -- a discrete device on the motherboard -- would be configured to fire interrupts periodically at a rate of X Hz.  Every time this "timer interrupt" went off, execution of the current program would be suspended (just like any other interrupt) and the kernel's scheduler code would decrement its timeslice.  When the timeslice got all the way to zero, the kernel would take the CPU away from the program and give it to another one.  The clock chip, being separate from the CPU, obviously runs in parallel with the execution of the program, but the kernel's bookkeeping work has to interrupt the program (this is the misty past we're talking about, so there is only one CPU, so kernel code and user code cannot run simultaneously).

Nowadays, the clock is not a discrete device, it's part of the CPU, and it can be programmed to do all sorts of clever things.  Most importantly it can be programmed to fire *one* interrupt after N microseconds, where N can be quite large; this allows the kernel to idle the CPU for a very long time (in computer terms; maybe, like, a whole second) if there's nothing constructive for it to do, saving power.  Meanwhile, it's hard to find a single-core CPU anymore, kernels do all sorts of clever tricks to push their bookkeeping work off to CPUs that don't have anything better to do, and timeslice accounting has gotten a whole lot more complicated.  Linux currently uses the "[Completely Fair Scheduler](http://kerneltrap.org/node/8059)" which doesn't even really have a concept of "time slices".  I don't know what FreeBSD's got, but I would be surprised if it was simple.

So the short answer to your question is "mostly in parallel, more so now than in the past, but it's not remotely as simple as a countdown timer anymore".

Comment: Hard to find single-core CPUs? Look closer at the market, those Atom D/N/Z are omnipresent like ocean water.

Comment: I knew someone was going to say that. Give it another chip generation ;-)